# Where to find produced Docker image

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to implement the example from this tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

I successfully compiled the package:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\rest_api>docker build -t springio/gs-spring-boot-docker .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  105.6MB
Step 1/5 : FROM openjdk:13-alpine
 ---> c4b0433a01ac
Step 2/5 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 010600c5a7d0
Step 3/5 : ARG JAR_FILE=target/rest_api.jar
 ---> Running in 8ba2e28e0870
Removing intermediate container 8ba2e28e0870
 ---> b453cd05cbd2
Step 4/5 : ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
 ---> dade5dd3eff2
Step 5/5 : ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
 ---> Running in e8a1f985f0fd
Removing intermediate container e8a1f985f0fd
 ---> cfa353eb23c5
Successfully built cfa353eb23c5
Successfully tagged springio/gs-spring-boot-docker:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.

C:\Users\Desktop\rest_api>
```

It's not clear for me where is the compiled package located? Can you guide me where it's located and how to mount it into Docker?

Docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:13-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=target/rest_api.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: the compiled jar is inside the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the "compiled package" (spring boot jar) you need to invoke `mvn package` first.

This command will compile the sources and create a JAR in the target directory of your project.

Since you're working with spring boot, you'll need to configure spring boot maven plugin (make sure it appears in the `pom.xml`) This plugin creates a special jar of spring boot applications with all the dependencies inside. It stores it in the `target` directory

So, after invoking `mvn package` command and before running `docker build` command go to `target` directory and make sure that you have a relatively big JAR of the application.

This explanation, I assume, answers the part of the question "where is the compiled package located?"

Now as for "how to mount to Docker" part of the question:

In the Dockerfile you use `ADD` command. This command takes the jar and "adds" it to the docker image (like into the filesystem of the container), so It will be available under /app.jar (because you also rename the artifact on the way)

Answer (score -1):

At build time, the jar file has been copied from your computer into the container and is since located at `/app.jar`. No need to mount it.

Comment: @michalk How? What would you think is accurate? The `ADD` command copies the file from `[build directory]/target/rest_api.jar` (the build directory is last argument in the call to `docker build`, in our case the current directory).

Comment: I think you should be more precise. Something like "copied from host system into the container". Note: I did not downvote.